# pandas display categories incorrect displayed in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, categories, display

I am trying to represent categories in matplotlib and for some reason I have categories overlapping on x-axis, as well as missing categories, but y-axis values present. I marked this with red arrows in the picture from the bottom of the question.

**The data is contained in sales.csv file that looks like this:**

```
date,first name,last name,city,cost,rooms,bathrooms,type,status
2018-03-04 12:13:21,Linda,Evangelista,Balm Beach,333000,2,2,townhouse,sold
2018-02-01 07:20:20,Rita,Ford,Balm Beach,818000,2,2,detached,sold
2018-03-08 07:13:00,Ali,Hassan,Bowmanville,413000,2,2,bungalow,forsale
2018-05-08 21:00:00,Rashid,Forani,Bowmanville,467000,2,2,townhouse,sold
2018-02-07 16:43:00,Kumar,Yoshi,Bowmanville,613000,3,3,bungalow,sold
2018-01-05 13:43:00,Srini,Santinaram,Bowmanville,723000,2,2,bungalow,forsale
2018-01-03 14:19:00,Maria,Dugall,Brampton,900000,4,3,semidetached,forsale
2018-05-04 19:22:00,Zina,Evangel,Burlington,221000,1,1,townhouse,forsale
2018-05-01 19:44:00,Pierre,Merci,Gatineau,3199000,14,14,bungalow,forsale
2018-05-31 18:10:00,Istvan,Kerekes,Kingston,1110000,4,5,bungalow,sold
2018-03-25 08:22:00,Dumitru,Plamada,Kingston,1650000,5,5,bungalow,forsale
2018-01-01 11:54:00,John,Smith,Markham,1200000,3,3,bungalow,sold
2018-05-07 15:30:00,Arturo,Gonzales,Mississauga,187000,3,3,bungalow,forsale
2018-03-07 22:20:00,Lei,Zhang,North York,122000,1,1,townhouse,forsale
2018-05-04 20:04:00,William,King,Oaks,,3,3,bungalow,sold
2018-03-04 13:05:00,Jeffrey,Kong,Oakville,,2,2,townhouse,forsale
2018-01-04 17:23:00,Abdul,Karrem,Orillia,883000,3,4,townhouse,sold
2018-03-01 13:09:00,Jean,Paumier,Ottawa,1520000,4,4,townhouse,sold
2018-02-01 10:00:00,Ken,Beaufort,Ottawa,3440000,5,5,bungalow,forsale
2018-02-15 11:33:00,Gheorghe,Ionescu,Richmond Hill,1630000,4,3,bungalow,forsale
2018-01-05 10:32:00,Ion,Popescu,Scarborough,1420000,5,3,semidetached,sold
2018-02-07 11:44:00,Xu,Yang,Toronto,422000,2,2,townhouse,forsale
2018-05-29 00:33:00,Giovanni,Gianparello,Toronto,1917000,4,4,bungalow,forsale
2018-03-25 08:27:00,John,Saint-Claire,Toronto,3337000,5,4,bungalow,forsale
2018-01-06 14:06:00,Ann,Murdoch Pyrell,Toronto,1427000,5,4,bungalow,forsale
2018-02-15 13:12:00,Claire,Coldwell,Toronto,3777000,5,4,bungalow,forsale
2018-01-02 09:37:00,Kyle,MCDonald,Toronto,,2,2,townhouse,forsale
2018-02-01 21:22:00,Miriam,Berg,Toronto,,4,4,townhouse,forsale
```

**The code to load the data and display the graph is below:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Load data
sales_brute = pd.read_csv('sales.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col='date')

# Fix the columns names by stripping the extra spaces
sales_brute = sales_brute.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())

# Fix the N/A from cost column
sales_brute['cost'].fillna(sales_brute['cost'].mean(), inplace=True)

# Draws a scattered plot, price by cities. Change the colors of plot.
plt.scatter(sales_brute['city'], sales_brute['cost'], color='red')

# Rotates the ticks with 70 grd
plt.xticks(sales_brute['city'], rotation=70)

plt.tight_layout()
# Add grid
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

**and the results looks strangely like this:**

[Incorrect display of categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLqJE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe we have different versions of matplotlib, but I can't use `plt.scatter` at all with `sales_brute['city']` as first argument.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Toronto'
```

Instead I made up a new x-axis:

```
x = range(len(sales_brute))
plt.scatter(x=x, y=sales_brute['cost'], color='red')
plt.xticks(x, sales_brute['city'], rotation=70)
plt.show()
```

Which results in:

[image: some stretching required to see the full names]

(some stretching required to see the full names)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am using mathplotlib ver 2.1.0. Based on your idea I went with this:  

x=sales_brute['city'].astype('category')
plt.scatter(x=x.cat.codes, y=sales_brute['cost'], color='red')

# Rotates the ticks with 70 grd
plt.xticks(x.cat.codes, sales_brute['city'], rotation=70)

because using range would repeat the names of the cities on the x-axis

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`plt.scatter` seems to be happy to take strings as the x-coordinate and arrange them in alphabetical order. `plt.xticks`, however, wants a list matching the number of ticks and in the same order.

If you change:

```
plt.xticks(sales_brute['city'], rotation=70)
```

to

```
plt.xticks(sales_brute['city'].sort_values().unique(), rotation=70),
```

you'll get the effect you want.